# Using External Certificates on a network that doesn't permit outbound HTTP/S access

Tags: network, authentication, certificates, ipsec, validation

Some highly secure networks and DMZs prevent all communication to outside hosts.  This can cause issues with validating externally signed data

I can guess that issues with signature validation occur when checking the certificates' CRL and OCSP data in many areas such as

- Authenticode & signed Powershell objects
- Authentication
- S/MIME
- Servers downloading and verifying patches, or signed AV updates
- ...?

How does one address the lack of external connectivity with regard to certificate revocation checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Revocation.** OCSP and CRLs are pretty well irrelevant these days.  They are [not very effective for security](http://www.imperialviolet.org/2012/02/05/crlsets.html).  And if you can't reach the revocation authority, no problem, the browser [happily ignores the network error and proceeds as if the certificates are unrevoked](http://www.imperialviolet.org/2011/03/18/revocation.html).  So inability to make outbound connections for OCSP or CRLs shouldn't pose a problem.

**Updates.**  The big one is downloading of updates (e.g., software updates, A/V updates).  I think you may want to add a whitelist to your firewall of allowed outbound connections, so that machines can still get their security updates.

For Windows updates, I think you want to allow access to TCP ports 80 and 443 on the following domains:

```
*.download.windowsupdate.com
*.windowsupdate.com
download.microsoft.com
ntservicepack.microsoft.com
windowsupdate.microsoft.com
*.windowsupdate.microsoft.com
wustat.windows.com
update.microsoft.com
*.update.microsoft.com
test.stats.update.microsoft.com
```

See also [Firewall rule to allow access to windows updates or other resources on a CDN?](https://serverfault.com/q/165601/111679).

Comment: Is it too broad to say that OCSP/CRLs aren't effective?  Or is it just not happening for web browsers notably HTTPS connections?  I don't understand why the author made a special case of EV certificates unless the industry wants to put technical teeth behind EV.  Also he seemed to neglect browser user certificate auth.  Isn't CRLS/OCSP used there? or is that just on the back end?

Comment: Nice point about the AV updates, and additional firewall exceptions.  I suppose I can get around the MSFT ports if I use a WSUS server.

Answer (score 0):

OCSP messages are encoded in ASN.1 and are usually accessed over HTTP.  If you are establishing a connection to a remote host then there should never be a problem accessing OCSP.  As a rule of thumb if you need a PKI then you need OCSP.

On a side note,  the PKI isn't always the best tool for the job.  Often packaging an application with the public key to verify a new update or other forms of mobile code is perfectibility acceptable.